# Cannot Upload PDFs with Firefox (Mimetypes)

Tags: file-uploads, uploads

I am having a problem specifically with uploading PDF files when using Firefox (27.0.1).

Currently, I have the following in my mimes.php file:

```
'pdf'    =>    array('application/pdf', 'application/x-download', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/binary', 'application/unknown'),
```

I have tried many variations of the above, and nothing has worked so far.

Has anyone found the proper type to add for PDFs that works with Firefox?

Comment: did this happen when u login as superadmin??

Comment: yes... but not if I upload the pdf straight from the admin panel.  This is an issue with Firefox specifically where it does not send pdfs with the proper mimetype when you submit them through forms on websites.

Comment: If anyone knows how I can get FreeForm to show me what mimetype it is getting and return that as part of it's returned upload errors, that would be amazing!  I can't even find a way to get my template to show me what mimetype was received from FF.

Comment: Assuming you're running the latest version (4.1.3), add the following code to line 232 of /system/expressionengine/third_party/freeform/act.freeform.php (move the foreach to line 233): `die('<pre>'.print_r($_FILES,TRUE).'</pre>');`. That should give you the mime-type as the server sees it.

Comment: @enga hi I reread your all comments here, so try this first login as subperadmin , create an EE native form(channel:form) and try to upload the same pdf file you success to upload form CMS and let me know if this work.

Comment: @Mark I am using version 4.1.3 and did as you said, but for some reason, the script is not actually dying as expected and printing the error, it is just continuing as usual and printing the error on screen about the filetype not being allowed.  (note that I am using Ajax to process the form)

Comment: @enga - Ah, sorry. In that case, the upload is probably being blocked by EE before it hits FreeForm.

Comment: Yes, sounds like it.  I am sure this is a case of not having a matching mimetype listed in EE's mime.php but I can't figure out what Firefox is sending the PDF as. :(

Answer (score 3):

I've seen instances where PDF uploads won't work in Firefox if you've got ExpressionEngine XSS filtering file uploads. In Admin -> Security and Session Preferences, set "Apply XSS Filtering to uploaded files?" to "No".

I'm not a fan of disabling security measures like this, but I've found no other solution.

Comment: I frequently need to turn off XSS filtering for uploads as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this is already something I had done.

Answer (score 2):

try to use this one

```
'pdf'    =>    array('application/pdf', 'application/x-download', 'application/download')
```

and tell me

and you can always solve this problem by rename the mimeTypes.rdf file which you can find in

AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\

Regard's.

Comment: I am going to try this one and see.  As far as renaming the mimeTypes.rdf file, that would be good for me, but still wouldn't solve anything for users of our site that happen to use Firefox.  Thank you, I will get back with whether those mimetypes work for me or not!

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work either. :(

Answer (score 0):

*-edited out-*

Going by http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/92552/ -> https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=332690#c24

edit:

Check out your mimeTypes.rdf and let us know if there's anything funky there, all the variants there are in your mimes.php, etc.

edit 2::

woops, sorry didn't realize there was more to the original array, thought it was just 3 types in there.

Comment: Thanks notacouch.  I've had a look at the .rdf and I am not seeing anything weird.   <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:application/pdf" NC:value="application/pdf"> <NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:handler:application/pdf"/></RDF:Description>

Answer (score 0):

Check this bolg, it seems that there are some solutions

http://mrvtech.blogspot.fr/2015/12/firefox-cant-upload-pdf-files-here-are.html